# PHP Warning plugin: A non-numeric value encountered

Tags: php

I'm getting the following error with a wordpress plugin:

> PHP Warning: A non-numeric value encountered on line 33

```
//Line 32 
$get_size = array_key_exists('icon_size', $instance) ? $instance['icon_size'] : '24';
//Line 33 
$circle_size = $get_size * 1.5;
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question. What the variable values? specify each input value. Which will help to answer the question

Comment: what `$instance` contents?

Answer (score 2):

issue is on this line,

```
$get_size = array_key_exists('icon_size', $instance) ? $instance['icon_size'] : '24';
```

your array key is exist and you are passing non numeric value to multiply with an integer. Make sure you are passing a numeric value in 
$instance['icon_size'] ! it has to be '10' or 10 ( any number quoted or not quoted doesn't matter but if you are passing other than number like any string. PHP will through that error you are currently facing now.